# PHP Postcode Checker

Tags: php, postal-code

I'm looking to create a basic postcode checker for a small business with a few stores across Australia. I just want the customer to input their postcode, and based on that postcode they would be redirected to their relevant local web site with local pricing etc. I was thinking just a simple if statement (e.g if submitted postcode is between 5000 and 5999 load South Australia page) but I'm not sure on how I would do this.

I have been looking at this: http://waww.com.au/ramblings/determine-state-from-postcode-in-australia but so far no luck

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: the function you refer looks very straightforward you can get state from `$state = findState($postcode)`. If you need more fine locality determination you may need to download the full postcode database and work with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a database solution is not wanted, maybe try this ...

```
if ($postcode > 999 && < 2001) {$destination = "http://example.com/go_here"};
if ($postcode > 2000 && < 3001) {$destination = "http://example.com/go_elsewhere"};
// ...

header('Location: ' . $destination);
```

Answer (score 1):

Although most people will tell you to use a database, **don't!**

The PHP function you posted is also the solution for your problem. It's ultra-fast, no connecting, no error handling, just call and forget. It might be possible to come up with a few optimizations, but at first glance it's just plain perfect to simply copy and use it. If it's becoming a bottleneck later on optimize it (the database would become a bottleneck thousands of years before this function does).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you saving the postcode in the database with a relation (could be manytomany if there are multiple stores in one city) to the existing store. Then just search in the database for the entered code and redirect the user.